# upload picture with rest cakephp3 and angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, cakephp

well I haver a form with plugen `ng-file-upload` but when I send the picture to the back end this recieve nothing. What I really need is to store the path of the image in the database, I also need to upload the image to the local server. But this is still not possible.

```
<form id="docsForm" class="form-horizontal" name="docsForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="submitDocsForm()" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="photo_document" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                    Documento escaneado:
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="file"
                           ng-model="vm.photo_document"
                           id="photo_document"
                           name="photo_document"
                           accept="image/*"
                           ngf-select ng-model="photo_document"
                           ngf-model-invalid="errorFile" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                    Descripcion:
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="descripcion" id="descripcion" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="superhidden" id="superhidden">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                        Agregar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="progress" ng-show="photo_document.progress >= 0">
                <div style="width:{{photo_document.progress}}%"
                     ng-bind="photo_document.progress + '%'"></div>
              </span>
            <span ng-show="photo_document.result">Upload Successful</span>
            <span class="err" ng-show="errorMsg">{{errorMsg}}</span>
        </form>
```

Well here in the picture I show you send the photo, but the answer does not receive anything in the photo data.

[image]

my controller is simple:

```
 $scope.submitDocsForm = function () {
            dataDocs = {
                photo: vm.photo_document,
                descripcion: $scope.descripcion
            };
            console.log(dataDocs);

            docsFactory.addDocuments(dataDocs).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

        };
```

controller cakephp3 for add documents, for save the pictre I,m using [cakephp upload](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-upload):

```
public function add()
    {
        $data = ['result' => 'fail', 'id' => 'null'];
        $errors = $this->Documents->validator()->errors($this->request->getData());
        if(empty($errors))
        {
            $document = $this->Documents->newEntity($this->request->getData());
            $document->photo = $this->request->getData('photo');
            if ($this->Documents->save($document))
            {
                $data = ['result' => 'success', 'id' => $document->id];
            }
        } else {
            $data['error'] = $errors;
        }
        $this->set(compact('data'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
    }
```

my model:

```
 public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('documents');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
            'photo' => [
                'path' => 'static{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}{primaryKey}',
            ],
        ]);
    }
```